# How to undo changes to passed parameters NavigationContext?

Tags: wpf, prism

i have a Grid showing details of a Person object. When a row is selected, i am showing the details in a separate Region.
When the user edits e.g. the First Name Textbox in the Details View, the changes immediately get reflected in the Grid.
When the user decides to Cancel the edit, i can undo the changes by replacing the object in the Details view, but the changes in the Grid view are not reverted.

in OnNavigatedTo of the Details View i have:

`_persons = navigationContext.Parameters["persons"] as List<Person>;`

i make a MemberwiseCopy of _persons[0] and show _persons[0] in the Details View:

```
PersonEdit = _persons[0];
_savedPerson = _persons[0].Clone();
```

All fields of the details view are bound to PersonEdit.
Changing the FirstName, which is bound to PersonEdit.FirstName the Grid shows the changed value.

When the user presses the "Cancel Edit" button, i want to restore the saved Copy.

tried both:

```
PersonEdit _savedPerson;
_persons[0] = _savedPerson;
```

This restores the changes done before the edit in the Details view, but the grid  stays unchanged.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Helmut

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should invest some time in building an undo-(redo?)-infrastructure. Commanding comes to mind.

Until then, because of

> When the user edits e.g. the First Name Textbox in the Details View, the changes immediately get reflected in the Grid

you should restore all the original values and the changes (i.e. the undo) will also be directly visible.

So do not clone and edit the clone, but keep the clone around and copy every editable value from the clone to the original object when the user clicks the undo-button.

Side note: if you use the default `Clone` implementation, you better be 110% sure that this is correct for your domain (and will be in the future).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.
I have decided to copy every single value back from my saved copy.
That did the trick.